Windows shared folder LAN transfers an order of magnitude slower than SFTP transfers between the same machines?
I have a Windows 11 laptop and a Windows 11 desktop. The desktop shares folders that the laptop accesses using either UNC paths or a mounted drive letter. I get about 4 MB/s (32 Mbit/s) reading or writing this way.
If I instead transfer my files via SFTP, I get ~40 MB/s (320 Mbit/s).
If I boot a Kubuntu live CD on both machines and transfer files using the shared folder on there, I get 40 - 45 MB/s (320 - 360 Mbit/s).
What could be making the Windows shared folder feature operate at 1/10th the speed of everything else?

It's not Windows Defender scanning things, because it happens even with excluded folders.
It's not anything else running in the background, because it happens even when both machines are fresh from-scratch OS reinstalls.
I'm transferring individual multi-gigabyte files, not folders of small ones, and the exact same files when I tested Kubuntu and SFTP.
It's not Windows Explorer, because the same speeds are seen using Robocopy. Likewise, rclone shows a ~4 MB/s speed if I transfer to my mounted network drive using a drive letter, and a ~40 MB/s speed doing the exact same transfer but over SFTP to the same machine.
iperf3 reports an average speed of 48.3 MB/s (387 Mbit/s) between them.
Connecting the laptop with an Ethernet cable results in the speeds tripling -- for both the Windows shared folder speed and the SFTP speed (so they go to ~12 MB/s and ~120 MB/s and remain off by a factor of ten).


+1 for testing and documentation of issue. You might try changing the Windows MTU to optimize speed, though I don't expect that to make a large difference: https://myrandomtechblog.com/cryptomining/change-mtu-size-in-windows-10/
